Folding a 40° coffee filter cone
EDIT: In an earlier version I botched the description. I mixed up the angles. The Chemex and V60 drippers are 60 degrees externally from the horistontal while Phoenix70 dripper pictured is 70 degrees, i.e. it is quite a bit narrower. The Chemex/V60 have filter cones that are 60° internally, but the Phoenix70 has filters cones that are 40° (not 70° as I wrote before) internally.
I was gifted a Phoenix70 coffee dripper that only takes 40° filter cones:

It makes delicious coffee. Unfortunately, the custom filters for the Phoenix70 cost about as much to ship to the UK (£9) as to buy (£11). I have Chemex 4-cup filters and V60 2-cup filters easily and cheaply available. The Chemex filter, when unfolded, is just one large rectangle (almost but not quite a square—if need be I could cut it to size).
So my challenge is to find a reproducible method for folding either of these filters into sturdy 40° cones for the Phoenix70. Is that possible? Can that be proved?
I don't mind how much the resulting cone protrudes either side of the dripper or whether it looks a bit odd.

Thanks I forgot!

A practical response: save your money, a Chemex filter will be fine. From its default fold, just pull the inner fold of the filter outwards a little, then crease. The image here actually yielded a cone pretty close to $70$ degrees by protractor. You'll know you have the right angle when you wet it prior to putting the grounds in and you see it lies fairly flush, the water will give you wiggle room.

Edit: For completeness, it is mathematically true that the Chemex double-fold will yield a cone with $60$ degrees at the apex. You can see that in the diagrams below. Reversing the logic, a cone with $70$ at the apex results from an initial fold of a little over $103$ degrees. The only downside of the pull-out method above is that the generator of the cone (the side) gets a bit shorter, you can see the original filter cone has dashed dimensions, the pull-out is a little shorter. But still plenty for a normal brew.

Edit #2 for smaller angle: My poor filter. In light of needing a narrower apex of $40$, you would need an angle of about $61$ degrees (for desired apex $\alpha$ use $180 \sin{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ to find the angle of your fold). Fortunately, this is just as easy as making a wide cone: from the default fold, fold one outer edge over to form the desired angle, then fold the lip, as in the picture below. And fold around the extra larger flap, it'll wrap around outside the cone.


This is brilliant and exposed a very silly mistake in my description, so so sorry... I mixed up the external angle of the dripper with the internal angle of the cone. I am actually looking for a narrower filter cone, not a wider one—i.e. 40º. My apologies and thanks for a great answer!

No worries - happy brewing! I'll have to check the shops around to see if I can find someone using this pointy Phoenix thing.

"You'll know you have the right angle" You mean the correct angle?
